# Notifying "experts" on specific subjects

Tags: discussion

The site is fairly diverse, no matter what it may seem. [This](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1159/opt-in-to-be-always-pingable-to-answer-questions/5497) question on Physics inspired me to post a modified version here, because I think it could be relevant.

The gist of the principle is that users can post information here about their specialties - that is, the areas where they feel they can best post high-quality answers. If there is a question related to a user's specialty, they can be notified, and hopefully post a good answer.

Let everyone know what you think, and post your information below!

Comment: I think this question should be asked in every SE meta site. But experts may also specify their certifications in different fields(if any)

Comment: Can't the "experts" just follow the relevant tags and those that want to notify them use those tags?

Comment: @quid It works for now (i.e. I constantly check the "Physics" tag), but eventually there are going to be a *lot* of tags in each area. For example, we already have "Experimental-physics" and "Theoretical-physics". But I see your point.

Comment: @user291957 Thank you; I've done this on Worldbuilding, too.

Comment: My Pleasure @HDE226868

Answer (score 2):

Good idea!

I am a bit of an eclectic eccentric - in that nothing bores me at all.

My main passion is [Earth Sciences](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/889/omen), specifically volcanology and atmospheric sciences. I used to work as an exploration geologist, so all aspects of the application of earth sciences fascinate me.

Like HDE 226868, I have a passion for [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/2449/omen), have so since a child, and especially after having being able to do some exoplanet hunting with one of the experts in the field.

[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/60063/omen), I live it, I teach it and have a dear passion for it.

On the practical side of things, [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions) is a way for me to focus my skills in a favourite program of mine - MS Excel (don't laugh!!)

Asides from these, I am passionate about [Science Education](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79366/science-educators?referrer=DuIQITVtb97MRAWyY3pk8g2), exploring [Scientific Imagination](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75912/scientific-imagination?referrer=DuIQITVtb94FuP7v0aO_3g2) and [Alternative History](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79097/alternative-history?referrer=DuIQITVtb960haiDNNem5w2).

Answer (score 1):

[Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/users/2153/hde-226868) and related topics.

I love astronomy, and have for a long while. I'll answer anything related to stars, black holes, planets - you name it.

[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/56299/hde-226868) and related topics.

I also love physics, especially the theoretical side. I'll answer conceptual questions, as well as ones about physicists. I'm considering physics as a career.

[Space exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/5963/hde-226868) and related topics.

Space exploration fascinates me. We're constantly journeying to further places, and pushing the frontier. I know a fair amount about the history of space exploration, especially the Space Race.